# Locale in SK Swidish

Tags: java, numberformatter

I know that the swidish number format should be like
"# ### ###"
Now let say that I have this number
10000000
when try this code snippest in java:

***NumberFormat.getInstance(new Locale("sv_SE")).format(10000000)***

the result

10,000,000

and when trying the following:

***NumberFormat.getInstance(new Locale("sv")).format(10000000)***

the output 
10 000 000

Why the difference come on ?

Comment: Probably has to do with the fact that `sv` is not a valid locale and `sv_SE` is, and an invalid locale is defaulting to something, probably your system locale. Not 100% sure though

Comment: But this is a java code and it should be going well
I will add extra thing that on javascript , using amcharts, I used the same sv_SE and the result was 1 000 000 which is the default format for Sweed
While in javacode it is only show the default format for sv only